# C++ Error with Data Types

Tags: c++, syntax

I keep getting a compilier error whenever I run this... I am quite sure it is just something stupid that I am overlooking, so I though I would let you guys try.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class hi
{
public:
    string run()
    {
        hi = "Hello.";
        return hi;
    }
private:
    string hi;
}

int main()
{
    bool end = false;
    string in = "";
    string out = "";

    hi hi;

    while(end != true)
    {
        cout << "Input a Command: ";
        cin >> in;
//        if(in == "help")
//        {
//            out = help.run;
//        }
        if(in == "hi")
        {
            out = hi.run;
        }

        cout << out;
        in = "";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
|6|error: new types may not be defined in a return type|
|6|note: (perhaps a semicolon is missing after the definition of 'hi')|
|18|error: two or more data types in declaration of 'main'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Please paste your code in your question, instead of providing an outside link. StackExchange regulations.

Comment: Codereview is for reviews of working code. It's not for getting your code to work.

Comment: needs a semi-colon at the end of the class definition (hi). Why is the member given the same name as the class? What is hi::hi ? A data member or a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the end of your program you are closing more curly brackets than you have opened. You need to remove the curly bracket right **before** `return 0;`

Also you need to terminate your definition of `class hi` with a semicolon after the closing curly bracket, right before the definition of `main()`.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Another happy customer.

Comment: What is hi::hi ? A constructor or the string member? There is no particular reason to give the member variable the same name as the class even if it does compile.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the semi-colon after your class definition.